# How to Save Application From Crash due to WebCore issues

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, swift, ipad

I have an UIWebView in my app and my App is almost consists on a WebView but some times my app crashes arbitrary show some crash log like 
"WebCore: WTF::HashTable, WTF::HashTraits >::add(WTF::String const&) + 40"
I think these crash logs are due to javascript and Html .Now I want to save my app from crash in such situations and want to implement Exception Handling .So kindly guide me how I can implement Exception Handling to escape from any WebCore,WebKit crash. Thanks